# ¿Cómo finalizar completamente la aplicación desde cualquier activity?

Tags: java, android, programación-móvil

Tengo una aplicación la cual quiero que se pueda finalizar completamente desde cualquier actividad y que esta no quede en segundo plano. 
La aplicación va a constar de 5 Activity's. En la tercera activity tengo el siguiente código.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    Log.i(TAG,"Me destrulleron");
    super.onDestroy();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(this.tiempoPrimerClick + INTERVALO > System.currentTimeMillis()){
        finish();
        return;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Vuelve a precionar para salir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    tiempoPrimerClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

El cual me termina la tercera Actividad y la segunda Actividad pero me deja en el MainActivity.

En la segunda actividad tengo el siguiente código

```
  @Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    Log.i(TAG,"Me destrulleron");
    super.onDestroy();

    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
} @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(this.tiempoPrimerClick + INTERVALO > System.currentTimeMillis()){
        finish();

        return;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Vuelve a presionar para salir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    tiempoPrimerClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Estando en esta actividad si la aplicación se cierra y se termina el proceso.

Ahora en el MainActivity tengo el siguiente código:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

Aun me encuentro revisando porqué en la tercera activity la aplicación no se cierra completamente. Sería de gran ayuda si me echan una mano.

Comment: Tengo entendido que android gestiona a su manera la memoria, es decir que si una app está cerrada, no debe consumir ni ejecutar tareas background y si android necesita memoria para otra app pues machaca a la tuya, lo único que haces de quitar completamente de memoria es cuando el usuario la vuelve abrir, se abrirá más lenta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A partir de la versión `>= API 16` puedes usar `finishAffinity()` pero existe una alternativa que funciona en `>= API 11`

**Método alternativo**

El método es cargar una `Actividad` encima de todas las demás eliminando su pila, y después cerrarla definitivamente.

Cada vez que quieras salir de todas las `Actividades` abiertas, al evento `onBackPressed` de todas ellas poner

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

y en el `MainActivity.java` capturar si hay un `intent` con valor de `EXIT` para así finalizar la aplicación en totalidad.

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
    finish();
}
```

Adaptado de las respuestas [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497151/activity-finishaffinity-vs-intent-flag-activity-new-task-intent-flag-activit) y [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001963/finish-all-activities-at-a-time)

Comment: it as useful for me, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con `finishAffinity();`

Cabe destacar que corresponde a la API de Jelly Bean y si te da error coloca

```
@TargerApi (Buil.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
```

arriba de la función donde estés usando lo dicho antes.