# ¿Hacer que una app finalice cuando se ponga en segundo plano?

Tags: android, android-studio

Quisiera saber cómo puedo lograr esto, si es matando todos los Activities, pues estoy haciendo una especie de Gestor de contraseñas.

Comment: Hey JFF, bienvenido!, Con respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, al menos agrega tu código, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haz intenado usar los metodos de onPause() y onResume() en el flujo de tu aplicacion?.. No hay un metodo exacto para querer ahcer lo que gustas pero sin duda alguna tienes que mandar el kill de tu app desde el metodo de onPause() por lo que entiendo.

Si buscas un poco mas de info, encontre esta pagina espero te funcione, de lo contrario te recomiendo que consultes el flujo de las apps para android, para cuando vayan de los diferentes estados y quieras ejecutar cosas entre estos estados, onPause, onResume, etc.

Espero y te ayude un poco. 
[Solution to detect when an Android app goes to the background and come back to the foreground](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.mx/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, el link que me diste me fue útil.

El código lo tenía en el onPause(); pero si iniciaba la app y abría otro Activity me la cerraba

Así que lo puse en el onStop(); y así sí me funcionó

Comment: Si **existe método del SDK para realizarlo, se llama finishAffinity()** incluso existen otros métodos para realizarlo en APIs inferiores a 16. Recuerda que estamos en SOes trata de agregar recursos en español, y agregar la parte más escencial de los links.

Answer (score 0):

Cada Activity tiene su propio ciclo de vida, si deseas detectar cuando se 
encuentra en segundo plano (background) sobre escribe el método `onPause()` :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //La app esta en segundo plano (background).
}
```

[¿Cómo saber si mi app está en segundo plano?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42671/c%C3%B3mo-saber-si-mi-app-est%C3%A1-en-segundo-plano/42674#42674)

En cuanto a como finalizarla se puede usar el método anterior para detectar la aplicación se encuentra en segundo plano, ahora veamos como finalizar la aplicación:

> ¿Hacer que una app finalice cuando se ponga en segundo plano?

Para esto puedes usar desde la API 16 el método [finishAffinity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity())

> [finishAffinity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()) : Termina esta actividad así como todas las
>   actividades inmediatamente debajo de ella en la tarea actual que
>   tengan la misma afinidad.

Por lo tanto tu código sería:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    finishAffinity()
    super.onPause();
}
```

---

Como complemente, con respecto a finalizar la aplicación puedes ver las opciones que sugiere @WebServeis en su respuesta:

[¿Cómo finalizar completamente la aplicación desde cualquier activity?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39283/c%C3%B3mo-finalizar-completamente-la-aplicaci%C3%B3n-desde-cualquier-activity)