# Como hacer para que una actividad finalice al pasar a segundo plano

Tags: android

Como puedo hacer en Android sdk para que una actividad finalice al pasar a segundo plano, pueden darme un ejemplo.

Comment: hola amigo, antes de preguntar puedes revisar en el sitio, tal vez la información ya se tiene: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107615/hacer-que-una-app-finalice-cuando-se-ponga-en-segundo-plano/107644#107644 saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo general existe un método para finalizar una actividad, pero el mismo no puede llamarse directamente, hablo de `finish()`, también esta el método `onDestroy()`, que se especifica mucho mas claro en la documentación oficial cuando mencionan el [ciclo de vida de una actividad - Actidades](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities?hl=es-419). Bien para hacer algo parecido a lo que quieres hacer debes puedes intentar lo siguiente.

Como bien es sabido cuando una actividad no es visible, quiere decir que la misma entra en `onStop()`, bien, también mencione que no puedes llamar a `finish()` o `onDestroy()` así de la nada, pero de esta forma puedes lograr lo que necesitas:

```
//Declaras un handler global para usarlo posteriormente en onResume y un booleano
boolean notResumed;
Handler myHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startActivity(new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class));
    //Acá abandonas la actividad en la que estas, de esta forma puedes ver en log como ocurre el proceso.
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    notResumed=false;
    //Eliminar las devoluciones de llamada en el Handler si ya existe
    if (myHandler != null) {
        // Envias nulo aquí para eliminar todas las devoluciones de llamada, todos los mensajes.
        // y eliminar también la referencia del ejecutable
        myHandler.removeCallbacks(null);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    notResumed=true;
    myHandler=new Handler();
    myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(notResumed)
                finish();
        }
    },10000);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("debug","onDestroy se ha llamado");
}
```

Al momento que la actividad entra en `onStop()`, y termine el tiempo que se ha seteado en el `onStop()`, la misma finalizará, el tiempo lo colocas tu, según lo necesites.